# Android /java echonest file upload error

Tags: java, android

So i had been trying to figure out how to upload the file on echonest servers for analysis but i am unable to

```
String[] args={"/storage/sdcard1/Music/Drive soundtrack/A Real Hero (feat. Electric Youth).mp3"};
            File file = new File(args[0]);

            if(!file.canRead())
            {
                printUsage();
                System.out.println("Insert a valid path!");
            }

            System.out.println("validd path!");
            EchoNestAPI echoNest = new EchoNestAPI("080NXJV4YHVLIVBFA");
            System.out.println("hello!");
            Track track  = echoNest.uploadTrack(file,true);

            System.out.println("uploaded!");
            track.waitForAnalysis((60*1000)/2);


            System.out.println("ID: "+track.getID());
            System.out.println("Artist: "+track.getArtistName());
            System.out.println("Title: "+track.getTitle());
```

I came across similar problems while searching over the internet but i couldn't come across a solution.

http://archive-com.com/page/3694036/2014-02-11/http://developer.echonest.com/forums/thread/365

http://developer1072.rssing.com/chan-22893681/all_p31.html#item617

http://developer.echonest.com/forums/thread/1624